# Specify the type for groovy-variable

Tags: java, groovy

I know the question may seem stupid, but I could not find the answer to it. How in the groovy-code explicitly specify the type of the transferred variable.
The problem occuse when the overloaded method called, the JVM chosing the wrong option.

```
bwo_NewService.overloaded(entityId,'somestr')
```

I know that entityId is instance of UUID, but app doesnt seem to share my vision.

Comment: Have you tried using `as`? See [here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.it/2009/09/groovy-goodness-as-keyword.html) for an example.

Comment: Thank you. Seems like i just couldnt type a proper search request for it.

Comment: For future reference, I searched for "groovy cast" and went from there.

Comment: It is language barrier. For the most parts in russian-language responds i found only basic about how awesome non-specified cast in groovy. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Have you tried using `as`? See here for an example. 
>   [Federico klez Culloca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/133203/federico-klez-culloca)